# is OTP needed if my state does not change?

Tags: erlang

I have an erlang project whose state is entirely read only, and composed of ets tables and a [compiled module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130382/erlang-gen-server-with-a-large-state). It takes a few seconds to build the tables when the code starts.

**What is the best way to package this so it can be used by other applications?**

Some other things to consider:

- There are no data contention issues or changing state, so it seems as if there is no need for a gen_server.
- I like being able to call `application:start/1` and have things "just work".
- Some process should own the ets tables. It seems like I should not leave that up to the client code.

The above leads me to think I should create an application, and call the setup code from the supervisor's `init/1` function, but I'm unsure if this is a silly way to approach it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the module is entirely static you won't need any processes in such an application. If you implement the `application` behavior in OTP you should be able to connect the ETS tables directly to the main application process (initiate the tables in the application `start/2` callback). That way you'll have a minimal process model, allowing you to skip both the `supervisor` and any `gen_server`.

You should certainly use OTP, but that doesn't mean that you absolutely must have a `supervisor` or a `gen_server`.

Use [`appmon`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/appmon/appmon_chapter.html) to view the process hierarchy of your application.

Comment: I like it! Thanks for the input. :)

Comment: I just went to do this and realized that the start callback needs to return `{ok, Pid}`. Normally `Pid` referrers to the top supervisor process. If that doesn't exist in my case, should I just return `{ok, self()}`?

Comment: Yes, that is the practice when running supervisor-less applications.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it up as a standard OTP application. `gen_server` isn't about maintaining state, it's about having a server which can handle requests (it's not called `gen_state` for a reason imho ;)). Create an OTP app and let people use it in the same way they would any other.

Comment: Can you think of an example of a stateless `gen_server` that shouldn't just be a regular module? In the past I've always considered state as a prerequisite for use of the behavior.