# Erlang OTP application design

Tags: architecture, erlang, erlang-otp

I am struggling a little coming to grips with the OTP development model as I convert some code into an OTP app.

I am essentially making a web crawler and I just don't quite know where to put the code that does the actual work.

I have a supervisor which starts my worker:

```
-behaviour(supervisor).
-define(CHILD(I, Type), {I, {I, start_link, []}, permanent, 5000, Type, [I]}).

init(_Args) ->          
  Children = [
    ?CHILD(crawler, worker)
  ],  
  RestartStrategy = {one_for_one, 0, 1},
  {ok, {RestartStrategy, Children}}.
```

In this design, the Crawler Worker is then responsible for doing the actual work:

```
-behaviour(gen_server).

start_link() ->
  gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
  inets:start(),        
  httpc:set_options([{verbose_mode,true}]), 
  % gen_server:cast(?MODULE, crawl),
  % ok = do_crawl(),
  {ok, #state{}}.

do_crawl() ->
  % crawl!
  ok.

handle_cast(crawl}, State) -> 
  ok = do_crawl(),
  {noreply, State};
```

**do_crawl** spawns a fairly large number of processes and requests that handle the work of crawling via http.

Question, ultimately is: where should the actual crawl happen? As can be seen above I have been experimenting with different ways of triggering the actual work, but still missing some concept essential for grokering the way things fit together.

*Note:* some of the OTP plumbing is left out for brevity - the plumbing is all there and the system all hangs together

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I apologize if I got your question wrong.

A couple of suggestions that I can make to guide you in a right direction (or what I consider being a right direction :)

1 (Rather minor, but still important) I suggest getting inets startup code out of that worker and putting it in application statup code (appname_app.erl). As far as I can tell you're using rebar templates, so you should have those.

2 Now, onto essential parts. In order to make a full use of OTP's *supervisor* model, assuming that you want to spawn a large a large number of crawlers, it would make a lot of sense to use *simple_one_for_one* supervisors instead of *one_for_one* (read http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html for more details, but essential part is: simple_one_for_one - a simplified one_for_one supervisor, where all child processes are dynamically added instances of the same process type, i.e. running the same code.). So instead of launching just one process to supervise, you will actually specify a "template" of a sort — on how to start worker processes that are doing real job. Every worker of that kind is started using *supervisor:start_child/2* — http://erldocs.com/R14B01/stdlib/supervisor.html?i=1&search=start_chi#start_child/2. None of those workers will start until you explicitly start them.

2.1 Depending on a nature of your crawlers, you might need to assess what kind of restart strategy you need for your workers. Right now in your template you have it set as permanent (however you have a different kind of supervised child). Here are your options:

```
 Restart defines when a terminated child process should be restarted. A permanent child process should always be restarted, 
 a temporary child process should never be restarted and a transient child process should be restarted only if it terminates 
 abnormally, i.e. with another exit reason than normal.
```

So, you might want to have something like:

```
 -behaviour(supervisor).
 -define(CHILD(I, Type, Restart), {I, {I, start_link, []}, Restart, 5000, Type, [I]}).

 init(_Args) ->          
     Children = [
          ?CHILD(crawler, worker, transient)
     ],  
     RestartStrategy = {simple_one_for_one, 0, 1},
    {ok, {RestartStrategy, Children}}.
```

I took a liberty of suggesting *transient* restarts for these children as it makes sense for this kind of workers (restart if they failed to do the job and don't if they completed normally)

2.2 Once you take care of the above items, your supervisor will be handling any number of dynamically added worker processes; and it will be monitoring and restarting (if necessary) each of them, which adds a great deal to your system stability and manageability.

3 Now, a worker process. I would assume that each crawler has some particular states which it might be in at any given moment. For that reason, I would suggest using gen_fsm (finite state machine, more about them available at http://learnyousomeerlang.com/finite-state-machines). This way, each gen_fsm instance you dynamically add to your supervisor, should send an event to itself in *init/1* (using http://erldocs.com/R14B01/stdlib/gen_fsm.html?i=0&search=send_even#send_event/2).

Something alone the lines of:

```
   init([Arg1]) ->
       gen_fsm:send_event(self(), start),
       {ok, initialized, #state{ arg1 = Arg }}.

   initialized(start, State) ->
       %% do your work
       %% and then either switch to next state {next_state, ...
       %% or stop the thing: {stop, ...
```

Note that doing your work could be either contained within this gen_fsm process or you might consider spawning a separate process for it, depending on your particular needs.

You might want to have multiple state names for different phases of your crawling if it deems to be necessary.

Either way, hope this will help designing your application in a somewhat OTP-ish way. Please let me know if you have any questions, I'll be happy to add something if necessary.

Comment: You also might want to consider ibrowse or lhttpc, as httpc in erlang distribution is known to be not that good

Comment: Careful with gen_fsm ... it has often too restrictive semantics.  Only use it when its an exact fit.  Most times gen_server is better fitting.

Comment: I cannot express how thankful I am that you went out of your way on twitter to write this up!

Answer (score 4):

Are you actually keeping track of any state in your gen_server?

If the answer is yes, it looks like you are doing things the right way. Note that since messages are serialized, with the above implementation you could not have two crawls going at the same time. If you need concurrent crawls, see the answer to my question [here](http://spawnlink.com/articles/an-introduction-to-gen_server-erlybank/).

If the answer is no then you can possibly ditch the server and the supervisor and just use the application module for any initialization code as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174503/is-otp-needed-if-my-state-does-not-change).

Finally, [lhttpc](https://github.com/oscarh/lhttpc) and [ibrowse](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse) are considered better alternatives to inets. I use lhttpc in production on my ad servers and it works great.

Comment: Which is the right way though? How do you call the function from gen_server? Neither of the above actually work.

Comment: re inets, it seems to have had some recent changes, and seems to be the most fully-featured of the available options. will check out the suggestions though, cheers.

Comment: I didn't understand that the call wasn't even being made successfully. It would be helpful to see your actual code so I could point at the problem. In short, you should export a function from the server like `crawl/1` (I'm assuming it takes a URL). The function would simply do: `gen_server:cast(?MODULE, {crawl, Url}).`. That will trigger your handler for the case: `handle_cast({crawl, Url}, State)` which will in turn call `do_crawl(Url)`. Seeing some OTP examples would help you understand the full process.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this problem would be to look into the Erlang Solutions "jobs" application, which can be used to schedule jobs (i.e., requesting pages) and let a separate system handle each job, bound the concurrency and so on.

You can then feed new urls into a process `crawl_sched_mgr` which filters the urls and then spawns new jobs. You could also let the requestors do this themselves.

If you don't want to use jobs, Yurii's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: well, jobs might be ok, but I thought the inquiry was rather about how would you use OTP for this, hence the answer I wrote.

Comment: Very true. I just wanted to put forth an alternative.